# HTML5 Video with custom controls

Tags: css, html, video

I am having big issue.
You need to know i am beginner with this.
I have this code

```
<video src="http://omniawebfactory.com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/video-za-SaB.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="player">
```

I want to add controls PLAY, PAUSE and MUTE/UNMUTE image button toggle.
So, i have images for play, pause, mute and unmute.
Only thing i need is mute button to be replaced on click with unmute button and reverse.
Keep in mind video starts muted, then if visitor want he can unmute it.
I hope i was clear enough.
I read a lot here on stackoverflow but there is now solution. what ever i try it won't work.
Please post me working example on JSFiddle

and icons need to be ON video, in left corner

Here are icons

play: http://omniawebfactory.com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/play-beli-1.png

pause: http://omniawebfactory.com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pause-beli-1.png

muted: omniawebfactory .com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/sound-off-beli-1.png

unmuted: omniawebfactory .com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/sound-on-beli-1.png

Comment: Guys please just find me some kidn of swf player with just PLAY; PAUSE and MUTE UNMUTE TOGGLE

Comment: in the JSFiddle that was in the comments from the deleted answer your controls were visible, just not correctly positioned. you'll need to use CSS to position them

Comment: i do not know what browser u are using but in firefox they are not visible

Comment: they are off screen because your video fills the fiddle. if you move the `<video>` tag below the controls you will see them, and then you can use CSS to position them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var video = document.getElementById('player');
 video.volume = 0;
var muteBtn = document.getElementById('mute');
var playPause = document.getElementById('play');
playPause.addEventListener('click',playPauseit);
muteBtn.addEventListener('click',mute);

function playPauseit(){
  if(playPause.src == 'http://omniawebfactory.com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pause-beli-1.png'){
    video.pause();
    playPause.src = 'http://omniawebfactory.com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/play-beli-1.png';
    }
  else{
    video.play();
    playPause.src = 'http://omniawebfactory.com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pause-beli-1.png';
    }
  }

function mute(){
 if(video.volume == 1){ 
 video.volume = 0; 
 muteBtn.src="http://omniawebfactory.com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/sound-on-beli-1.png";
 }
 else{
  video.volume = 1;
  muteBtn.src="http://omniawebfactory.com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/sound-off-beli-1.png";
 }
}
```

```css
.buttons{
display:block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:black;
float:left;
}
#control{
width:1000px;
height:50px;
clear:both;
background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<video src="http://omniawebfactory.com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/video-za-SaB.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" id="player"></video>

<div id="control">
<img class="buttons"src="http://omniawebfactory.com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pause-beli-1.png" id="play"/>
<img class="buttons" src="http://omniawebfactory.com/unik/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/sound-on-beli-1.png" id="mute">
</div>
```

Comment: That javascript for mute you wrote, to toggle mute/unmute icon.
IS this possible to do with play and pause.
So i have only play and mute button?
I tried to modify code with play and pause functions, but it doesn't seem to work.
I am sorry for bothering you but i am really lame at this, and I am a woman too as you can notice :D

Comment: Gender has nothing to do with coding but rather, experience. Oh, and the code is modified so that you can read them easily. :DDD

Answer (score 0):

There's already a built-in control for you. Just add control to video tag.

Comment: Did you read my whole question?
I want to add my own image for play, pause, and mute-unmute toggle button to change on click.
Just pictures of play, pause mute/unmute, 3 buttons

Comment: You are the best!
THanks a LOT!

Comment: Please post that link as separate answer so i can accept it